# In Excel, "if greater than 0 and less then 10 then "x", but if greater then 10 and less then 20 then "y" in same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a formula to calculate shipping based on price but I have only been able to find this:

```
=IF(AND(D2>0.01,D2<13.51),4.51,"")
```

Basically it reads "If the total purchase (D2) is greater then $0.01 and less then $13.51 apply $4.51 as the shipping fee. This works for the one fee but I need it to apply the other fees as well and I cannot seem to figure out how to do multiple greater than, less than in one formula.

So I need to be able to add multiple of that same code and change the numbers, but I can't figure out how to do multiple without getting an error.

Comment: I'm guessing there is some mapping to item price & shipping price. If so, you can use `LOOKUP` to import the shipping cost based on a input range, or in this case, a max threshold. See https://exceljet.net/formula/lookup-value-between-two-numbers or https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4782-excel-vlookup-between-two-values.html

Comment: Other than VLOOKUP, probably the better choice, you can also do multiple IFs for a single row by using the "else" part of the IF:
IF(AND(D2>0.01,D2<13.51), 4.51, IF(AND(D2>13.50,D2<20), 9, IF(...)))
Or whatever the next price tier and shipping cost are.

Comment: Excel is not Google Sheets. Which of the two are you using? Please only use appropriate tags.

Comment: Do you mean there are multiple shipping fees? How do you work out which one to apply? Is it based on the value of D2? If so, nested IFS with ANDS are an easy solution

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP with approximate match sounds like it would be the easiest if you have a lot of shipping prices.  The lookup table is in grey and you can setup however you like.  If column 'B', put the formula `=VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$E$5,2,TRUE)`  The TRUE is was provides the approximate match.

A nested IF would work, but would be horrible to manage.  Using the VLOOKUP, anyone could maintain the lookup table.

[image: example picture]